# Replace/Remove colons of Strings inside a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, replace

Simple question:

I got following List:

```
['nordhessen:abfall_b', 'nordhessen:anschlussstelle_b']
```

And I want to get this List:

```
['nordhessenabfall_b', 'nordhessenanschlussstelle_b']
```

How do I remove the colons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = ['nordhessen:abfall_b', 'nordhessen:anschlussstelle_b']

new_data = [item.replace(':', '') for item in data]
```